# Infinity laplacian of radial functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, laplacian

I have to compute the infinity laplacian
$$
\Delta_{\infty}u=\sum_{i,j=1}^n\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x_ix_j}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_j}
$$
of a radial function $R(r)=R(|x|)$. The answer is $\Delta_{\infty}R(r)=R''(r)R'(r)^2$. My attempt is the following. We have
$$
\frac{\partial R}{\partial x_i}=R'\frac{x_i}{r},\qquad \frac{\partial R}{\partial x_j}=R'\frac{x_j}{r}
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial^2R}{\partial x_ix_j}=\frac{x_ix_j}{r^2}\left(R''-\frac{R'}{r}\right).
$$
So
$$
\Delta_{\infty}R(r)=\sum_{i,j=1}^n\frac{x_ix_j}{r^2}\left(R''-\frac{R'}{r}\right)\frac{x_ix_j}{r^2}R'^2=\left(R''-\frac{R'}{r}\right)\frac{R'^2}{r^4}\sum_{i,j=1}^nx_i^2x_j^2=\left(R''-\frac{R'}{r}\right)R'^2
$$
but this does not coincide with the answer due to the term $\frac{R'}{r}$. I cannot say the error. Can someone help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake comes from forgetting the case when $i = j $ in the double derivative. The actual formula is:
$$ \frac{\partial^2 R}{\partial x_i x_j} = \frac{x_i x_j}{r^2} \left( R^{\prime \prime} - \frac{R^\prime} {r}  \right) + \delta_j(i) \frac{R^\prime}{r}$$

Therefore the infinite laplacian is:

$$ \Delta_{\infty}R(r)=\sum_{i,j=1}^n\left( \frac{x_ix_j}{r^2}\left(R''-\frac{R'}{r}\right) + \delta_j(i) \frac{R^\prime}{r} \right) \frac{x_ix_j}{r^2}R'^2 $$

Using your same computations, we have that
$\begin{align} \Delta_{\infty}R(r) & = \left( R^{\prime \prime} - \frac{R^\prime}{r}\right) R^{\prime 2} + \sum_{i,j= 1}^n \delta_j(i) \frac{R^\prime}{r} \frac{x_i x_j}{r^2} R^{\prime 2} \\ & =  \left( R^{\prime \prime} - \frac{R^\prime}{r}\right) R^{\prime 2} + \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{R^\prime}{r} \frac{x_i^2}{r^2} R^{\prime 2} \\ & = \left( R^{\prime \prime} - \frac{R^\prime}{r}\right) R^{\prime 2}  + \frac{R^\prime}{r}R^{\prime 2} \\ & = R^{\prime \prime} R^{\prime 2}. \end{align}$

Comment: In the derivative $\frac{\partial^2R}{\partial x_ix_j}=\frac{x_ix_j}{r^2}\left(R''-R'\right)+\delta_j(i)\frac{R'}{r}$ shall we have the term $\frac{R'}{r}$ in $(R''-R')$ in place of $R'$, right?

Comment: Yes! I fix it right away.